# TFHpple only parse texts before <br> tag

Tags: objective-c, hpple

This is the HTML:

```
<p id="content">Every Sunday, our Chef proposes a buffet high in color.
<br>
A brunch either classic or on a theme for special events
<br>
Every Sunday at the restaurant
</p>
```

And Here is my code:

```
NSString *u = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http//mydomain.com%@", _currentNews.url];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
NSData *paHtmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

TFHpple *paParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:paHtmlData];

NSArray *array = [paParser searchWithXPathQuery:@"//p[@id='content']/text()"];
TFHppleElement *ele= [array objectAtIndex:0];

_currentBody.text = [ele text];
_currentTitle.text = _currentNews.title;
```

I want to parse all text between `<p id="content"></p>` without the `<br>`

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 NSString*  webSIteSource=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:u]encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    webSIteSource=  [webSIteSource stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br />"withString:@" "];
    webSIteSource=[webSIteSource stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<blockquote>" withString:@" "];
    webSIteSource=[webSIteSource stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</blockquote>" withString:@" "];
```

Just garb all website content to nsstring then remove all "br" tag!
That's it!